# Is there a way to know the composition of a Team GO Rocket before going into the fight?

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday during the GO Rocket event, I had something annoying. Not knowing the composition of an opponent before going in meant I could wipe only because I came in with a few water types only to face a Venosaur.

So is there a way to know what you'll be facing before going into a fight with GO Rocket?

Comment: Guess you haven't felt the rush of the final phase in the Battle Factory of Johto's Battle Frontier, where you only know the 1st Pokemon of the foe. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The "taunt" line that the grunt says (right when you're confirming your team) will hint at the general makeup of the grunt's team--particularly the third Pokemon.

- BUG – Go, my super bug Pokemon!
- DARK – Wherever is a light, there is also shadow.
- DRAGON – ROAR! … How’d that sound?
- ELECTRIC – Get ready to be shocked!
- FAIRY – Check out my cute Pokemon!
- FIGHTING – This buff physique isn’t just for show!
- FIRE – Do you know how hot Pokemon fire breath can get?
- FLYING – My bird Pokemon wants to battle with you!
- GHOST – Ke…ke…ke…ke…ke…ke!
- GRASS – Don’t tangle with us!
- GROUND – You’ll be defeated into the ground!
- ICE – You’re gonna be frozen in your tracks.
- NORMAL – Normal doesn’t mean weak.
- POISON – Coiled and ready to strike!
- PSYCHIC – Are you scared of physics that use unseen power?
- ROCK – Let’s rock and roll!
- STEEL – You’re no match for my iron will!
- WATER – These waters are treacherous!
- RANDOM – Winning is for winners, Don't bother, I've already won, and Get ready to be defeated

[Source 1](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/team-rocket-invasions-everything-you-need-to-know/), [source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/chpipe/can_we_have_a_compilation_of_all_possible_team/) (credit to Wondercricket), plus [hints](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/team-go-rocket-battle-guide/) as to good compositions to bring.

Comment: Great answer, but those sources left out a few. Currently, the grunts with taunts *Winning is for winners*, *Don't bother, I've already won*, and *Get ready to be defeated* will throw out a random combination ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/chpipe/can_we_have_a_compilation_of_all_possible_team/))